# Why is json-server's (nodejs plugin) package.json running when I do git push?

Tags: node-modules, git-push, json-server

Any time I run git push, a package in node_modules runs which breaks my push and I get the error you see in my git error response.

My setup is pretty basic. (Gulp,few other dependencies, and json-server) none of the other projects are trying to build their packages from git push.

I resolved this problem by deleting the package.json of json-server for now. I would still like to understand why git would/node would be forcing this to run.

Thanks anyone!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright a friend suggested searching in my .git dir and look at the hooks. He was right. json-server hooks.

A little backstory in the event you find this question. I was messing around with the json-server package myself (without loading it in a clean dir i know.. silly me). I made a few changes and built the project (which I'm guessing at that point something happened to my projects .git hooks).

Anyway deleted the hooks and all is well now!

[image]